# Not able to use char* with URLDownloadToFile

Tags: c++, winapi, urlmon

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <UrlMon.h>
#include <cstring>
#pragma comment(lib, "UrlMon.lib")
using namespace std;

int main()
{
char* appdata = getenv("APPDATA"); //Gets %Appdata% path
char* truepath = strcat(appdata, "\\USR\\file.dat"); // file location

cout << truepath ;
HRESULT hr = URLDownloadToFile(NULL, _T("http://localhost:8080/upload.php?name=Huh?" + truepath), _T("d"), 0, NULL);
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

This is my code above, and I am getting an error on this lane:

```
HRESULT hr = URLDownloadToFile(NULL, _T("http://localhost:8080/upload.php?name=Huh?" + truepath), _T("d"), 0, NULL);
```

The compilation error it's giving me says that "+ truepath" is not possible to be used there.

I've tried .c_str() and few other ways but can't manage it to work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't concatenate a char* with a string literal using the + operator. Use std::string/std::wstring

Comment: Also, that `strcat` is trashing the environment variables memory block.

Comment: Are building for Ansi or UNICODE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// ANSI Build
std::string appdata( getenv("APPDATA") ); 
appdata += "\\USR\\file.dat";
std::string url( "http://localhost:8080/upload.php?name=Huh?" );
url += appdata;
URLDownloadToFile( NULL, url.c_str(), [...] 

// UNICODE Build
std::wstring appdata( _wgetenv( L"APPDATA" ) ); 
appdata += L"\\USR\\file.dat";
std::wstring url( L"http://localhost:8080/upload.php?name=Huh?" );
url += appdata;
URLDownloadToFile( NULL, url.c_str(), [...]
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, do you mind if you add an Unicode example as well?

Comment: `error C2664: 'URLDownloadToFileW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char *' to 'LPCWSTR'` and `1>    Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast`

Comment: weird. c_str() return const wchar_t * for a std::wstring. Please double check your code.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot add two pointers.

The `truepath` is a pointer to char.

And when you say `"http://localhost:8080/upload.php?name=Huh?"` it returns a pointer to a `char`. So, you are trying to add two pointer and here is what standard says about the additive operator...

```
5.7
For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic or unscoped enumeration 
type, or one operand shall be a pointer to a completely-defined object 
type and the other shall have integral or unscoped enumeration type.
```

Also, you have to allocate memory for the `truepath` variable or else it will crash.